# Find the norm of functional

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the functional  from $l_2$.
$$
x=(x_n)\mapsto \sum \frac{x_n+x_{n+1}}{2^n}.
$$
What is  the norm of the functional?

Comment: Can you represent this functional in the form $\sum x_ny_n$ where $y=(y_n)\in\ell_2$? It means it has the form $x\mapsto \langle x,y \rangle$. Cauchy-Schwarz might help then. (Or if you have already learned that $\ell_2^*=\ell_2$, the result should be immediate.)

Comment: See also this similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234115/find-the-norm-of-an-operator-on-ell-2

Answer (score 1):

It should not be very difficult to rewrite your functional to the form
$$x\mapsto \sum x_n y_n$$
where $y=y_n\in\ell_2$.

Then the norm of this functional is precisely $\|y\|_2$, i.e., it is the same as the $\ell_2$-norm of the sequence $y$.

To see this, just notice that you have the functional of the form
$$f(x)=\langle x,y \rangle,$$
where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the standard inner product on $\ell_2$.

From [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality) you have
$$|f(x)| = |\langle x,y \rangle| \le \|y\|\cdot\|x\|,$$
i.e., $$\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|} \le \|y\|$$
which means that $\|f\|\le\|y\|$.

The opposite inequality follows from
$$f(y)=\langle y,y \rangle =\|y\|^2$$
or 
$$\frac{f(y)}{\|y\|}=\|y\|.$$

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak Thank you!